# Check if each() index 1 et index 2 has .prop( 'checked' )

Tags: javascript

How to check in a each() function if the first and the second matched element have the prop checked ?

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitBtn', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            $checkboxItems = $('input:checkbox[name="checkbox-acceptance"]');
        
            
        $checkboxItems.each(function( index ){

            // if index 0 and index 1 have .prop( 'checked ' ) do stuff ..

        }       
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use `each` for this. Just check the values with simple indexing:

```js
if ($checkboxItems[0].checked && $checkboxItems[1].checked)
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of the existence of a `each` function, however if you need to check if the first two elements of an array are true I will go with @David Thomas solution

```
$checkboxItems.slice(0,2).every((el) => el.value);
```

Comment: So you've copied a comment and submitted it as your own answer? Regardless of the attribution, you can't just copy some one else's solution. You also missed off a crucial part of the original solution meaning this won't even work.

Comment: @Cjmarkham This is perfectly acceptable to turn a  comment into an answer. Unfortunately the comment (and thus the answer) is using the wrong property however

Comment: @charlietfl May i ask you which property is proper here then ?

Comment: @colapsnux `el.checked`